# What is the best practice of 'restarting' a thread?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Consider the following Python function:

```
def make_request(arg1, arg2):
    make http request
```

I want to be able to create 5 threads that all call the `make_request()` function, however, I want it to be the case that as soon as one thread finishes another identical thread (making the same call to the `make_request()` function) starts. It seems that python does not actually support the 'restarting' of threads, so I thought to make it so that the `make_request()` never terminates by means of a `while True:` loop like so:

```
def make_request(arg1, arg2):
    while True:
        make http request
```

However, this does not seem like best practice and I am not sure if this approach may have unintended consequences.

Comment: Is just a simple for loop launching the thread and then waiting for it with a join not sufficient? I.e. `for _ in range(5): thread = threading.Thread(target=make_request); thread.start(); thread.join()`

Comment: You can use a pool of threads of a fixed size. These can be fed from an iterable containing work items. As soon as the first thread finishes it will be given the next item.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the while loop. Remember the KISS principle

Comment: "this does not seem like best practice" why not? as long as you mark the thread as a daemon, and don't hold any resources that aren't properly cleaned up on exit, this looks fine to me. I use `while True` loops all the time. I would even argue for daemon threads, it's the canonical way to do it.

Comment: @alkasm no, because I don't want them to be joined, because I don't expect it to terminate.

Comment: @user13834264 Ah I understood your post to mean: you have 5 threads, and you want them to run one after the other, not that you have 5 different functions that you want to loop indefinitely. In that case, a `while True` is fine and common. If you need cancellation ability, just pass a `threading.Event` to the thread and loop `while not event.is_set()`, and someone external could flag `event.set()` to flag all threads to stop.